# heximal to binary in cpu-miner

Tags: c, hex

I am analyzing the code for the cpu-miner project. There is a function named hex2bin that converts hexadecimal strings to binary longs. I tried the function myself, but I got every time a different output from the same input. Why does this happen and why don't they just use strtol(hexstring, 0, 16)?

This is the hex2bin function:

```
bool hex2bin(unsigned char *p, const char *hexstr, size_t len)
{
    char hex_byte[3];
    char *ep;

    hex_byte[2] = '\0';

    while (*hexstr && len) {
        if (!hexstr[1]) {
            applog(LOG_ERR, "hex2bin str truncated");
            return false;
        }
        hex_byte[0] = hexstr[0];
        hex_byte[1] = hexstr[1];
        *p = (unsigned char) strtol(hex_byte, &ep, 16);
        if (*ep) {
            applog(LOG_ERR, "hex2bin failed on '%s'", hex_byte);
            return false;
        }
        p++;
        hexstr += 2;
        len--;
    }

    return (len == 0 && *hexstr == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

And my main function for testing:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char p[40];

    memset(p, 0, 40);
    hex2bin(p, "e1b3f5c0", 4);

    printf("strtol: %x\n", strtol("e1b3f5c0", 0, 16));

    printf("hex2bin: %x\n", p);
}
```

Testing gave:
1.

```
strtol: e1b3f5c0

hex2bin: e6474980
```

2.

```
strtol: e1b3f5c0

hex2bin: e0cc9980
```

Comment: Please provide your test code and test output.

Comment: *"I tried the function myself"* - we're not in the habit of assuming that attempt was without flaws of its own. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62459892/edit) to include that code as part of a proper [mcve], including all required test input and resulting output of said-same.

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings? You should. Also, ASLR is nice.

Comment: No, I will look at that

Comment: `%x` expects `unsigned int` but you are providing `long` in one case and `unsigned char *` in the other.

Comment: If the goal is a faster alternative to `strtol` then this function is a complete waste of time since it uses `strtol` internally and does a whole lot of other useless junk that takes up cycles for no reason. If you wanted one that was fast you'd write a compact `switch` statement or use a look-up table.

Comment: the `? true : false` part is redundant. Just `return len == 0 && *hexstr == 0` is enough

Comment: the posted code does not compile! please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: what is `applog()`

Comment: regarding: `if (!hexstr[1]) {`  a hexidecimal string can have 0x00` anywhere within its contents so this is not a valid `if()`